# Apache mod-rewrite(RewriteRule) filter for https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want the user to redirect to `https`except specific `URL` pattern.
For example, if User types `sacyolo.com`, I want him to redirect to `https://sacyolo.com

But when user types sacyolo.com/api/....,`
 I don't want him to redirect to https.
I tried

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sacyolo.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sacyolo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sacyolo.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sacyolo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put this code in the .htaccess file at root folder.